# Stop nullability warnings from entity framework queries that include nullable navigation properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, nullability

Consider an entity framework core model with the following two entities:

```
public class RiskAssessment {
  public string Title { get; set; } = string.Empty;
  public Guid? ActivityID { get; set; }

  public Activity? Activity { get; set; }
}

public class Activity {
  public Guid ID { get; set; }
  public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

Activity is a nullable navigation property.

I can write a query like the following using these entities:

```
return await session.RiskAssessments
    .Select(x => new {x.Title, x.Activity.Name}).ToListAsync();
```

This query runs without problems and if Activity is null it returns null for the second field. However Visual Studio highlights x.Activity with a null reference warning. Can anyone recommend a way to avoid this warning? I can surround the query with a pragma to disable the warning, but that's quite ugly. I could disable warnings for the entire class, but the class may contain other methods where I'd like to be warned of potential null references. Is there a recommended way to approach this that I've missed?

EDIT:
I hadn't specified this was for entity framework core in the question - added that now. I should also point out an additional option that works, but it's still quite nasty as it adds code complexity:

```
return await session.RiskAssessments
    .Select(x => new {x.Title, x.Activity==null?null:x.Activity.Name}).ToListAsync();
```

In its favour the extra code is ignored by entity framework when generating the underlying SQL query

Comment: @PoulBak Sadly no, you can't use null propagating operators in an entity framework query

Comment: You can use the long form of this and I've updated the question to reflect this. I'd say this represents the least worst option I've considered so far

Answer (score 1):

Guess this is a "Kernighan's Teddy" moment. As soon as I edited the question in response to Poul's suggestion the answer leapt out at me:

```
return await session.RiskAssessments
    .Select(x => new {x.Title, x.Activity!.Name}).ToListAsync();
```

The null forgiving operation *is* supported in EF Core queries. Hopefully this will point someone else in the right direction!